# Query para retornar valores de recorrências, que ainda não foram criadas no banco de dados

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, query, active-record

Preciso fazer uma consulta no banco de dados onde os registros ainda não estão salvos. Vou explicar melhor:

Em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo, o usuário pode cadastrar uma despesa recorrente, ou seja, que irá se repetir todos os meses/dias (conforme a escolha do usuário). Com isso eu crio um job que irá criar uma despesa (vai criar um registro na tabela `despesas`) na data configurada e agendar a criação da próxima.
Essa despesa recorrente pode ter uma data predeterminada para encerramento ou pode ser para sempre.

O que eu preciso é fazer uma consulta que irá somar as despesas por mês, exemplo:

**tabela** ***`recorrencia`***

[image: tabela]

E ainda eu tenho a tabela onde estão as despesas:

**tabela** ***`despesas`***

[image: despesas manuais]

Digamos que hoje fosse dia 01/12/2015 e gostaria de saber o valor das minhas despesas até dia 30/04/2015.
Preciso que retorne o seguinte:

[image: tabela2]

Ou seja, calcula quando uma despesa recorrente irá gerar uma despesa, juntar com a tabela despesas e fazer o cálculo.

Como eu poderia fazer essa consulta por sql? com uma view ou algo assim?

Estou utilizando o banco de dados postgresql com a linguagem de programação Ruby on Rails.

Obrigado

Comment: Pensou em criar o registro com uma "flag" do tipo previsto/realizado , no lugar do "job" uma "trigger" na tabela de RECORRENCIA povoaria a de DESPESAS, a sql seria simples tratando a "flag".

Comment: Uma outra solução mais simples seria utilizar apenas uma tabela chamada despesas, colocando um campo chamado `tipo CHAR(1)` que irá identificar o tipo desta despesa. Assim ficaria muito mais simples na hora de fazer o select e a somatória das dispesas.

Comment: @Motta, o problema é que eu não posso utilizar essa flag, pois pense, eu tenho uma despesa (como é o caso do aluguel do exemplo a cima) que não tem uma data determinada para terminar. Se o cliente fizer uma consulta para saber qual é as despesas estimadas dele para daqui 6 meses deverá trazer esse aluguel, e por isso não posso inserir registros na tabela `despesas`, pois não tenho uma data limite.

Comment: @antunesleo_ obrigado pela dica. Na verdade eu faço de 2 maneiras, 1 exatamente como você falou (para caso de despesas e receitas), mas também preciso fazer de outra forma onde eu tenho contratos de venda, que irá gerar uma venda e posteriormente uma lançamento na tabela de `financas` (que no meu exemplo coloquei como despesas para simplificar a explicação).

Comment: @Bmucelini , minha ideia é criar o registro de prévia e sinalizar de alguma forma que é prévia , quando efetivar basta trocar a flag , a cashflow pode ir neste registro diretamente.

Comment: @Motta, o problema é que não tem como eu criar esse registro de prévia, pois dependendo da configuração da recorrência é impossível eu criar um registro prévio, pois como pode se tratar de uma recorrência para sempre não tenho uma data limite para cadastrar todas as despesas previamente com uma flag de não pago. Desculpe se não foi isso que quis dizer, se entendi errado poderia explicar melhor sua colocação? cite um exemplo para que possa entender com mais clareza =). Obrigado

Comment: @Bmucelini , entendi uma outra solução seria uma view ou procedure retorndo um curso , montando uma linha de despesa prevista com base na tabela "recorrencia" , a ideia está meio tosca mas seria isto

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM despesas 
WHERE start_date BETWEEN ("01/01/2016") AND ("31/01/2016")
```

Comment: Mesmo que esta resposta seja uma boa sugestão, seria melhor você responder com respostas mais completas. Você pode elaborar mais sua resposta por favor?

Comment: Essa query não condiz com a questão.